# The stalk of a curve at a regular point is a valuation ring of the function field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a curve over a field $k$ (irreducible reduced separated $k$-scheme of finite type). Then a closed point $x\in X$ is regular if and only if $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a discrete valuation ring. But why is $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ a valuation ring of $k(X)$? That is,

> If $x\in X$ is regular, how do we show that for non-zero $f\in k(X)$, either $f\in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ or $f^{-1}\in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$? Alternatively: why $k(X)$ is the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$?

I take for granted [Tag 00PD](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PD) (hence, its application to $A=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$).

I can prove it for $X=\mathbb{A}_k^1$ but I don't know how to proceed in the general case.

Comment: Hint: $k(X)$ is the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Now write an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ as $u\pi^n$ for $u$ a unit, $\pi$ the uniformizer, and $n$ a non-negative integer. What does the quotient of two of these look like?

Comment: The fact that $k(X)$ is the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is exactly what I don't know how to show (just edited the question to make it clearer). The thing is that this isn't true in higher dimensions.

Comment: What? That's always true! If $A$ is a ring and $p\subset q$ are prime ideals of $A$, then $A_p$ is a localization of $A_q$. Now apply this to an affine open neighborhood of $x$ with $q$ the prime ideal corresponding to $x$ and $p$ the zero ideal (corresponding to the generic point).

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, yeah, you're right that the map $\operatorname{Spec} (S^{-1}A)\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ always induces isomorphisms on stalks. What isn't true in dimension $>1$ is that the stalk at a regular point of an irreducible variety is a valuation ring of the function field (on $X=\mathbb{A}_k^2$, the rational functions $x/y,y/x$ lie in $k(X)\setminus\mathcal{O}_{X,0}$). That's what got me confused (plus my wobbly knowledge regarding smoothness/regularity). All clear now .